# Actionscript 3 : pass a variable from the main fla to external as file

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm beginner in actionscript 3, and I'm trying to pass a variable from the main fla to external as file.

How can I do that passing of variables??

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your fla file set : `var myvar;` outside any function

```
function whatever(_op){
  var test = _op + "test";  //what ever
  myvar = test;            // this is it
}
```

inside your external as file : `root.myvar`

Comment: The problem here is that my variable is inside a function !