# How to pass variables from .fla file to .as file in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I have a .fla file names test.fla and I have this variable in it:

```
import Main;

var my_var;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void
{
 my_var = "Maziar";
 //trace(my_var);
}
```

I have a .as file called Main.as.

I want to pass **my_var** from test.fla to the Main.as.

I will really appreciate, if you can help me in this matter!

It is noticeable that I have used the method mentioned in "[Actionscript 3 : pass a variable from the main fla to external as file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603049/actionscript-3-pass-a-variable-from-the-main-fla-to-external-as-file)", but it does not work for me!!!

I wrote in my Main.as:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main()
    {
        if (stage)
        {
            init();
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForMyVar);
    }

    private function waitForMyVar(e:Event):void
    {
        if (my_var != null)
        {
            trace(my_var);
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForMyVar);
        }

    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }
 ...
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the constructor `Main` in your ActionScript document file is run before the code found within the frame. When you are attempting to access the `my_var` variable in your AS document it has not yet been declared in the frame.

So, we need to wait for Flash to run the frame. This can be done using an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener.

### *Example:*

**Timeline Code (.fla file)**

```
var my_var:String = "my variable";
```

**Document Code (.as file)**

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForMyVar);
        }

    private function waitForMyVar(e:Event):void {
        trace(my_var);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForMyVar);
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, it appears `my_var` is not assigned a value until the user has clicked the stage. An adjustment could be made in the `waitForMyVar` function to wait for `my_var` to be non-null.

### *Example:*

```
if(my_var != null) {
    trace(my_var);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, waitForMyVar);
}
```

---

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my question. I have done what you said in your answer exactly, but it shows me this error: 1120: Access of undefined property my_var.

Comment: Strange. The code works on my machine. Double check for any typos you may've made. If you come up empty, please upload your fla and AS files.

Comment: Please look at to my query again, I have edited based on your answer!

Comment: I think I see the problem. The removeEventListener line should be in the if(my_var != null) block. Otherwise, the listener is removed immediately and doesn't check again to see if my_var exists yet. This should fix the issue. Once I clicked the stage, my_var was assigned the value "Maziar" and it printed out correctly. I've updated my answer - sorry for the confusion! Hope this helps.

Comment: I put the removeeventlistener in if, but it still shows me the error: 1120: Access of undefined property my_var!!!!!!!

Comment: I've copied your code exactly, making the removeEventListener change referenced earlier as well as changing extends Sprite to extends MovieClip to avoid error 1180.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131845/discussion-between-phasma-and-maziar).

Comment: the error is in line: if (my_var != null) and line : trace(my_var);

Answer (score 0):

Use static class members.

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    static public var globalVar:* = 1;

    public function doWhatever():void
    {
        trace(globalVar);
    }
}
```

Then in FLA:

```
import Main;

var M:Main = new Main();
// or use sprite instance of Main

M.doWhatever();
Main.globalVar = "Hello World!";
M.doWhatever();
```